# Where can I view the current usage of my Pixel 6's Tensor Processing Unit, image signal processor and Tensor security core?

Tags: google-pixel-6, resource-monitoring

I read on https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/pixel-6s-tensor-chip-inside-the-brains-of-googles-newest-flagship/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220308223142/https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/pixel-6s-tensor-chip-inside-the-brains-of-googles-newest-flagship/)):

> In the case of Google's design, the eight-core CPU is integrated with a 20-core Arm Mali-G78 MP20 GPU, a Tensor Processing Unit machine learning engine, an advanced image signal processor for photography, a Tensor security core, a "context hub" for ultra-low power capabilities, and 8MB system cache. Tensor also includes a 4MB CPU L3 cache and is built on the 5-nanometer manufacturing node.

I wonder where I can view the current usage of my Pixel 6's Tensor Processing Unit, image signal processor and Tensor security core?.

Comment: You simply can't. You can not even monitor CPU usage without root or adb. And the only reason you can monitor CPU usage in the first place is because it is exposed by the Linux kernel in the proc. the Tensor Processing Unit is not exposed by the Linux kernel, so you can not monitor it even with root